# Executing Nexmark benchmark suite on Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am attempting to run the Nexmark benchmark suite on Google Dataflow, I read the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java/testing/nexmark/) and I think I know the general setup.

However, one thing missing from the documentation is the initial setup, it seems to provide a lot of running parameters but no actual command on what to download, compile and execute.

How can I start the benchmarking process?

Edit:

I downloaded the Apache Beam repo and executed the following command according to the documentation:

```
./gradlew :sdks:java:testing:nexmark:run \
    -Pnexmark.runner=":runners:google-cloud-dataflow-java" \
    -Pnexmark.args="
        --runner=DataflowRunner
        --suite=SMOKE
        --streamTimeout=60
        --streaming=true
        --manageResources=false
        --monitorJobs=true
        --project=${PROJECT}
        --zone=${ZONE}
        --workerMachineType=n1-highmem-8
        --stagingLocation=${STAGING_LOCATION}
        --sourceType=PUBSUB
        --pubSubMode=PUBLISH_ONLY
        --pubsubTopic=${PUBSUB_TOPIC}
        --resourceNameMode=VERBATIM
        --manageResources=false
        --numEventGenerators=64
        --numWorkers=16
        --maxNumWorkers=16
        --firstEventRate=100000
        --nextEventRate=100000
        --ratePeriodSec=3600
        --isRateLimited=true
        --avgPersonByteSize=500
        --avgAuctionByteSize=500
        --avgBidByteSize=500
        --probDelayedEvent=0.000001
        --occasionalDelaySec=3600
        --numEvents=0
        --useWallclockEventTime=true
        --usePubsubPublishTime=true
        --experiments=enable_custom_pubsub_sink"
```

However, I ran into a new issue regarding bindings, the error is below:

```
> Task :sdks:java:testing:nexmark:run FAILED
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/andy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.30/d35953dd2fe54ebe39fdf18cfd82fe6eb35b25ed/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/andy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.30/c21f55139d8141d2231214fb1feaf50a1edca95e/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <false, false>
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:316)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:254)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1936)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:144)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:327)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.nexmark.Main.runAll(Main.java:106)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.nexmark.Main.main(Main.java:467)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sdks:java:testing:nexmark:run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup, you'll have to download the [apache/beam](https://github.com/apache/beam) repo.

Go to the root directory, then execute the Gradle tasks following the examples in the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java/testing/nexmark/).

Comment: Hi, I attempted to download the repo and run the command given on the documentation. However I ran into a SLF4J issue. I updated the question to reflect the new progress.

Comment: Can you check if you are using Java 8 or 11? IIRC, Java 14 might not be compatible.

Comment: As per my error log, I should be using Java 11

Comment: The SLF4J logs are just warnings. You can ignore them for now. The real failure is from parsing pipeline options in Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <false, false>. The problem is there are 2 --manageResources=false set in the command. Removing the extra line resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem

Comment: Quick add-on, there is a warning saying that `WARNING: Prefer --sdkContainerImage over deprecated legacy option --workerHarnessContainerImage` but I did not specify that option. How can I use the new option?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because `--manageResources=false` occurs twice in the command line above.  Remove one of the instances to fix the problem.